# Creating a dataframe using declared variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe to assist in downstream calculations. All **"MineralVars"** need an NA value in this 1-row dataframe. MineralVars will always change in length and variable names, so I can't create the dataframe by inputting each Mineral one at a time. I need to create it using the string 'MineralVars'.

```
# Declare variables
MineralVars <- c("Al", "Cu", "Pb")


# Create helper dataframe
Placeholder_df <- data.frame(make = "Placeholder", modelid = "Placeholder",
                             unitno = "Placeholder", compart = "Placeholder",
                             MineralVars = NA, meterread = NA, order = NA)
```

My desired dataframe would look like this;

```
Desired_df <- data.frame(sampledate = NA, make = "Placeholder", modelid = "Placeholder",
                            unitno = "Placeholder", compart = "Placeholder", oilchanged = "Placeholder",
                            Cu = NA, Pb = NA, Al = NA, meterread = NA, order = NA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do an assignment

```
Placeholder_df[MineralVars] <- NA
```

and remove the "MineralVars"

```
Placeholder_df["MineralVars"] <- NULL
```

---

Or use `add_column`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
add_column(Placeholder_df,.before = "MineralVars", 
    !!!setNames(rep(NA,length(MineralVars)), MineralVars))  %>%
      mutate(MineralVars = NULL)
 #      make     modelid      unitno     compart Al Cu Pb meterread order
#1 Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder NA NA NA        NA    NA
```

and assign (`<-`) it either 'Placeholder_df' or a new object